# two different action on single button click?

Tags: android, button, multiprocessing

I have a button i need two action to be taken place ,that is when i open my app for the first time after installation it should preform a task .after the first  launch it did not want to perform the first action  how can i implement this?

I implement this,

```
private int _clicks = 0;
k = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    if(count == 1)
         //do whatever
    if(count == 2)
         //do whatever
    if(count == 3)
         //do whatever
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that you have performed the task already. So I suggest you store a value in the SharedPreferences Which you set after performing the task and recheck before handling any other click in the future.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if(!prefs.getBoolean("WAS_INITIALIZED", false)){
    // will only be executed after the first run. 
    // remember that it was initialized
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("WAS_INITIALIZED", true);

    // put you code which should only be run once here ..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `SharedPreferences` object to act as a "flag". First time your app opens, set some flag in the `SharedPreferences` object. Check the value of this flag in your button `onClickListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Create file in SD card for your actions. Modify the file according to your requirements, So whenever your application launches, it will read the file and react according to the actions you written there.

Try this.

Without having a global variable you can't change the action, So the global variable will be placed in SD card. try to understand this.